# When to use _Notnull_ in C++?

Tags: c++, notnull, wchar, sal

Can someone provide insight when to use `_Notnull_`? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
void WriteIt(_Notnull_ CONST WCHAR* sMsg, _Notnull_ CONST WCHAR* sFileName)
{
    FILE* stream;
    errno_t err = _wfopen_s(&stream, sFileName, L"a+");
    if (err == 0)
        if (stream)
            {
            fwprintf_s(stream, L"%s", sMsg);
            fclose(stream);
            }
}
int main()
{
    WCHAR *sMessage = new WCHAR[16]();
    WCHAR *sFile = NULL;
    sFile = NULL;
    WriteIt(sMessage, sFile);
}
```

Yet, the `_Notnull_` lets the function run. I can't find any documentation on how/why to use it with examples.

Comment: `_Notnull_` is not standard C++. Where did you see it used?

Comment: It's a SAL annotation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6504?view=msvc-170

Comment: This looks like a Visual Studio [SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170) feature but I've never seen `_Notnull_` before.

Comment: Best answer would be to not use it at all. And use std::string too.

Comment: This seems to be [the documentation for SAL annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-parameters-and-return-values?view=msvc-170) and `_Notnull_` is not mentioned.  (Although `_Ret_notnull_` is.)  I am wondering how @JeffR found this and why they believe they should use it.  I suspect it may be for MS internal use only.

Comment: @DrewDormann Came up when running code analysis.

Comment: It is probably an internal MSVC annotation intended to ease the implementation of the guideline support library `not_null` one: [`gsl::not_null`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f23-use-a-not_nullt-to-indicate-that-null-is-not-a-valid-value). As it is not documented in SAL, a non Microsoft internal programmer should not use it.

Comment: From `sal.h`: `//
// Pointer null-ness properties
//
#define _Null_                            _SAL2_Source_(_Null_, (), _Null_impl_)
#define _Notnull_                         _SAL2_Source_(_Notnull_, (), _Notnull_impl_)
#define _Maybenull_                       _SAL2_Source_(_Maybenull_, (), _Maybenull_impl_)`

Comment: SAL is a static thing; that is, it will watch (at compile time) for any calls to your function that may be passing in `nullptr`, and give you a compiler warning (if you have that enabled in your build). SAL doesn't do anything at runtime to prevent your function from being called.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @François Andrieux. Looks like it is used when doing a code analysis from within Visual Studio, where the analyzer can pinpoint if an incoming pointer could be NULL. Here is what the code analyzer says with `_Notnull_` is included: `Warning C6387 'sFile' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'WriteIt'.` Very helpful!